# How can I make this work with different columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to use Column L and N.

I tried L2:N2, but that also takes column M.

```
Const FirstCellAddress As String = "L2"
```

Comment: Use a comma instead of a colon: `Range("L2,N2").Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a comma instead of a colon to make a list of cells...

Ex:

```
Range("L2,N2").Select
```

or a list of sub-ranges:

```
Range("L2,N2,A:B,C5:F6").Select
```

So think of a comma like a `and` and a colon like a `between`